# why does compiling `*.clj` sources execute code as well?

Tags: clojure

I have the following non-sensical `*.clj` file:

```
(ns bar.zar.Foo
  (:gen-class :main true))

(println "foo")

(defn -main [& args]
   nil)
```

When compiling it to `*.class` (`clojure.lang.Compile`) with the following Ant target:

```
<target name="compile-clojure" description="Compile Clojure sources." depends="resolve">
  <mkdir dir="${cljbuild.dir}"/>
  <java classname="clojure.lang.Compile"
        failonerror="true"
        fork="true">
    <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    <sysproperty key="clojure.compile.path" value="${cljbuild.dir}"/>
    <arg value="${project.MainClass.name}"/>
  </java>
</target>
```

I see on the output:

```
 [java] Compiling bar.zar.Foo to /home/[ommitted]/build
 [java] foo
```

That is, the `(println "foo")` expression was evaluated during compilation. Why is that? Does it have to do with the *"Lisp blurs the compile-time / runtime distinction"* thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The unit of compilation in Clojure is the **top level s-expression** which is read, expanded, evaluated, and often stored in the namespace as the file is loaded. There is no separate compile phase for the whole file. Doing it this way **allows you to write function that define other functions**, types, DSLs etc. and is the building block of the macro system.

put anything you don't want run into an init function, then include a call that function from main (or wherever your code starts)